# RunInstances operation: The parameter 'iamInstanceProfile.name' may not be used in combination with 'iamInstanceProfile.arn'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

This is my code. Is there any problem with this code? It is showing some error!

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'us-east-2')
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sdh',
            'VirtualName': 'ephemeral1',
            'Ebs': {
                'Encrypted': False,     
                'Iops': 500,
                'VolumeSize': 100,
                'VolumeType': 'io1'
            },
        },
    ],
    ImageId='ami-XXXXXXXXX',
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='KeyName',
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/instance',
        'Name': 'instance'
    },
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='stop',
    PrivateIpAddress='XXX.XX.XX.XX'
)
```

It is showing the error:

> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>   botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: The parameter 'iamInstanceProfile.name' may not be used in combination with 'iamInstanceProfile.arn'

Comment: the method used for creating an instance is correct with boto3. Looks like some issue with your IAM role assigned with name 'instance'.

Answer (score 7):

It is complaining about this:

```
IamInstanceProfile={
    'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/instance',
    'Name': 'instance'
},
```

It is saying that you cannot specify *both* `Arn` and `Name`.

The reason is that the ARN uniquely identifies a resource, so the Name is not required. However, I'll admit that the documentation doesn't state this.

So, just remove the `Name` entry.

Comment: if i am using any one of them. its also showing the error!
when i removed this section of my code, it started working! Now the question is "how will system know iam profile of anyone if the code is working dynamically?"

Comment: If you just provide the Arn without the Name, what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you can only pass either the `Arn` or the `Name` parameter in the `IamInstanceProfile` dictionary. Unfortunately the Boto3 docs are a bit misleading here and lead to the impression that both can (or even have to be) passed in the call.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem here, when I refer the Boto3 documentation. Because that has not clearly mentioned that, we have to use either ARN or Name.

We can not use both in the code.

I have changed the code as below. it's working fine for me.

```
instances = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-0b639f0eba318b4fc',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.micro',
 KeyName='dev-secret',
 IamInstanceProfile={'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::3256666666:instance-profile/IAM_ec2_role'})
```